# Javascript function is undefined on onclick event of anchor tag

Tags: javascript, html

I am not able to access javascript function in onclick event of the anchor tag.

In some cases it is working and in some cases , not.

Can any body tell why it is happening.

HTML CODE -

```
<a  href='#'  class="btn waves-effect waves-light bg-blue" id="startDeviceScan" onclick="call286Dart123('CollectSysInfo', '3c6c3e33bb65e8331bf4c91c0670492e');" >start device scan </a>
```

Javascript function :

```
function call286Dart123(a,b) {
    console.log(a + "\t" + b);
}
```

Fiddle link

[Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/o3ncv7pm/)

Comment: saying something does not work is not helpful. what error massage are you getting? also if you can tell us where in the page is your script included(head/end of body)? I notice the function has the word dart in it, are you doing some kind of code generation from the dart language?

Comment: @user1852503 please check the fiddle and error is **function is not defined** as mentioned at the beginning.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**EDIT** Due to what @Dellirium pointed out in the comment, I've revised my answer to reflect the true issue here. The solution would still work, however.

<s>The problem is that JSFiddle makes the JavaScript run on document load by default. This means that the JS is loaded *after* the HTML, and therefore it wouldn't have been defined at the time the `onclick` event was initialized in the HTML.</s>

It seems to be a problem with **closures**. If you have "Load Type" set to "onload" in JSFiddle, this is what it does internally (you can check the developer console):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        window.onload=function(){
            function call286Dart123(a,b) {
                console.log(a + "\t" + b);
            }
        }
    //]]> 
</script>
```

This means that it is *wrapped* in in an anonymous event handler to the `onload` event. And since variable (and function) scopes are bound by functions in JavaScript, this makes them not available to the global scope

**Solution**: To fix this, under the "JavaScript" menu, change "Load Type" to "No wrap - in &t;head>". It's that easy =).

See [this JSFiddle fork](https://jsfiddle.net/jlam55555/o3ncv7pm/1/) as a working example.

In other words, this would simply change it to (again, you can verify this by visiting the developer console on my JSFiddle):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        function call286Dart123(a,b) {
            console.log(a + "\t" + b);
        }
    //]]> 
</script>
```

In which, `cal286Darkt123` would be defined in the global scope (outside any other functions).

For more info on closures, check the [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

Comment: @UgoT. Try running the examples and the Fiddle link I provided and seeing the difference.

Comment: Even if you put the script tag in the bottom of the body, effectively loading it AFTER the `<a>` tag, it still works. Due to this I do not think the issue in itself is with timing of the event initialization, since by the time the script in the bottom of the `<body>` tag is run, the anchor is already loaded. Or does the event initialization happen after ALL the elements are loaded?

Comment: @Dellirium I didn't notice that. I guess then it's a case of closures. I'll edit my answer to reflect this.

Comment: @Dellirium See my update. That should be the correct reason.

Comment: @JonathanLam same thing is happening in my local file.I was suspecting the same. I've defined the function in the body tag at the beginning and the anchor tag is defined at the end of the body tag, then also it is saying function is undefined.

Comment: @DhananjayJadhav Again, make sure it is not contained in any function. If this is not the case, can you also post the code for your local file?

Answer (score 3):

Don't use onclick attribute to run JavaScript if you can help it. Instead use [event listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) or JQuery [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method.

```
<a id="startDeviceScan">Do Something</a>
```

Vanilla JS:

```
<script>
   var el = document.getElementById("startDeviceScan");
   el.addEventListener("click", your_func, false);
</script>
```

JQuery:

```
$( "#startDeviceScan" ).on( "click", your_func(1234));
```

If you need to fetch an elements attributes for the argument such as the '1234' you can use [data- attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) and reference them with JS or [JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

[JSBin example](https://jsbin.com/pimomulani/edit?html,console,output)

Comment: This only provides an alternate solution, but does not answer the OP's question on *why* his code doesn't work.

Comment: You are right, I am highlighting best practice in the hope that the OP can use an alternative method to the one he is using which may help avoid weird shit like this in the first place.

Comment: how to pass dynamic values to `.onclick()` event listener.

Comment: by storing the dynamic values in [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) and fetching with [dataset property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset). A JSBin example is [here](https://jsbin.com/pimomulani/edit?html,console,output)

Answer (score 0):

Works for me :

```html
<script>
    function call286Dart123(a,b) {
     console.log(a + "\t" + b);
    }
</script>

<a class="btn waves-effect waves-light bg-blue" id="startDeviceScan" onclick="call286Dart123('CollectSysInfo', '3c6c3e33bb65e8331bf4c91c0670492e');"  href='#' >start device scan </a>
```

Comment: This provides an alternate solution but does not answer OP's original question of *why* his code didn't work.

Comment: So to answer this question do we have to debug JSFiddle? OP hasn't said even if it's just in JSFiddle or in a local environment or whatever...