# MVC function is not defined at onclick?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

i got this error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: updateShift is not defined
>   at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick`

i already looking for this problem and not fixing mine.

so here is my view

```
<div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-anchor-top-left dropdown-has-anchor" id="data1">
    <ul>
        @foreach(var shift in Model.ShiftModelList)
        {    
            <li><a onclick="updateShift('@item.EmployeeId')">@shift.ShiftId</a></li>
        }
</div>
```

javascript in the _layout.cshtml

```
function updateShift(empId)
{
    $.post('@Url.Action("updateShift","jadwal")',{empId:empId } function(data) {
        alert("suksess");
    })
}
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: Seems like a `comma` is missing after {empId:empId }

Comment: @MuhammedShevilKP i think you are right, i miss the comma. thanks you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function updateShift(empId) {
    $.post('@Url.Action("updateShift","jadwal")',{empId:empId } ,function(data) {
      alert("success");
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: the code worked :). just like @Muhammed said, i miss the comma. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your view is being rendered before your layout, so you need to wrap your JavaScript in a document ready function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function updateShift(empId) {
    $.post('@Url.Action("updateShift","jadwal")',{empId:empId } function(data) {
      alert("suksess");
    })
  }
});
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: i tried but the error still exist. thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

I hope the below link provides reason for the error and also the solution.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38372808/3397630

As per my understanding For this type of error, Its seems that we need to cross check the two things.

1. Scope of the javascript function is bounded
2. proper reference of the script files.

Additional info/same error:https://forums.asp.net/t/2116708.aspx?Uncaught+ReferenceError+AddRecord+is+not+defined+at+HTMLButtonElement+onclick+

Hope it will be helpful, kindly let me know your thoughts or feedbacks
Thanks

karthik