# Javascript script doesn't work with html

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-code

I just got into web development and decided to create a test project to see how things work.

My html code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>
        title
    </title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jstest.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>heading1</h1>
    <button onclick="runcode()">click me</button>
</body>



</html>
```

And the script is this:

```
function runcode(){
alert("clicked"); 
}
```

I don't exactly know why the script is not working. I have put it right before the  to ensure that the button loads first but it still didn't work

Comment: Did you read the console output? My guess is your path to your jstest.js is wrong. Is it in a js folder?

Comment: Does ist alert "clicked" if you move `alert("clicked")` outside the function?

Comment: Yes it does.Why doesnt the function work then?

Comment: Can you try change the button to something else. Like try `<span onclick="runcode()">click me</span>` and let us know if that works

Comment: I made a Fiddle of this to try things out on: https://jsfiddle.net/5mseL4tu/

Comment: The span also works

Comment: The fiddle doesnt work on me

Comment: No, it doesn't work, it's just an easier place to try things out...

Comment: I believe the function definition is coming *after* the `onclick` attribute assignment and, thus, it can't find the function. On JSFiddle the issue seems to be different. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38372808/4824627), it's due to the settings on JSFiddle, creating the function inside the `window.onload` scope instead of globally

Comment: I don't think this is the issue.When i changed the button to span the function worked, that means the function was already defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the comments, can you change the code you have with those little bits:

```js
function runcode(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("clicked"); 
}
```

```html
<h1>heading1</h1>
<button onclick="runcode(event)">click me</button>
```

From [MDN Webdocs about the button type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attr-type) they say:

> The type of the button. Possible values are: submit: **The button
>   submits the form data to the server. This is the default if the
>   attribute is not specified**, or if the attribute is dynamically changed
>   to an empty or invalid value.

That's means, you click the button which then submit's data and depending on the setup it refreshes the page. This is why you don't see the `alert`. The alert happens after the submit. Now the [event.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

> method tells the user agent that if the event goes unhandled, its
>   default action should not be taken as it normally would be.

So with that you stop it from doing the default stuff. Because now you want your function to work, which in first place has to stop the default behaviour to move on whith whatever you want. In this case alert something.

Comment: Well... I did not expect this to be the problem. Thanks for the info! Also is this a common problem between elements?

Comment: @harambe it is only a problem with elements which submit or try to follow a link like `<a>, <submit>, <button>`. So if you try the same with a `<a>` tag which has a `href="some-url"` the same happens as it did with the `<button>`